# Why isn't all of my 'store' list elements floating right?

Tags: html, css

I have a list where I want to "sort" into two columns. I do this by adding two classes and floating these left and right.

But for some reason not all elements that is supposed to be on the right side, is floated right. [See my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g66zX/2/).

In this list, there are no `store` list items, only `brand` items. But still one brand item is floated left. Why is that?

The list is a result of jQuery Autocomplete, so I can't change the way the list is created. [I've tried](http://jsfiddle.net/PMfb8/6/) :)

```
// HTML
<ul class="ui-autocomplete main-search">
    <li class="ui-autocomplete-category store">
        <h3>Stores</h3>
        <div class="no-match"> No matches found</div>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-autocomplete-category brand">
        <h3>Brands</h3>
    </li>
    <li class="brand ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a href="#" class="ui-corner-all">BARRATS</a>
    </li>
    <li class="brand ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a href="#" class="ui-corner-all" >Barrie</a>
    </li>
    <li class="brand ui-menu-item" role="presentation">
        <a href="#" id="ui-id-5" class="ui-corner-all" >Barrio Santo</a>
    </li>
</ul>

// CSS
ul { width: 500px; }
li { width: 250px; }
li.store { float: left;  }
li.brand { float: right;}
```

Comment: _“But still one brand item is floated left. Why is that?”_ – because there is enough space for the element underneath the “Stores: No matches found” LI … this is just how float works.

Answer (score 1):

You have to clear floats:

```
li.brand { float: right;clear:right;/*Add clear:right*/}
li.store { float: left;clear:left/*Add clear left*/}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g66zX/4/)

Comment: What's gonna happen when there will be left floated elements? I think you will see "steps"

Comment: @Morpheus, you're right. Suggestions to how it may be solved?

Comment: Is allowed to change html?

Comment: @Morpheus I've tried, but Autocomplete doesn't like that.  See my second js fiddle link in my questions or answer this question :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24814445/autocomplete-widget-returns-undefinde-element-on-selection